# Append the div content jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I have a div with content like this

```
 <div><strong>some content
 ....</strong></div>
```

How can I add another element to the div after `<strong>`, how to add `<span>` element after `<strong>` ?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use `append` on your `div` element:

```
$('#divId').append('<span>Hi</span>');
```

It will insert the `span` element inside the `div`, at the end of the child node list.

**Edit:** In response to your comment, to remove it, since you added the element with `append`, you can get it selecting the last-child:

```
$("#divId span:last-child").remove();
```

Or you could remove all the `span` elements within the `div`:

```
$("#divId span").remove();
```

Comment: Gr8 it works, how can I remove the span element? after I added it ?

Comment: Sorry, but, is there any reason for wrapping `'<span>Hi</span>'` in a jQuery object? You can append straight HTML...

Comment: @J-P: Yes, you're right, my fingers are getting too much used to type `$()` :-) edited...

Answer (score 1):

If the `<div>` is the only one on the HTML page in question:

```
$('div strong').after('<span>Span element</span>')
```

See http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/after#content

Answer (score 0):

[append](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/append#content) and [after](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/after#content) are easily found in the documentation